# Find % of days of the week using timestamp from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, count

I have a MySQL DB table called 'purchases' populated with records of various transactions. I wish to find out what % of transactions have occurred on particular day of the week and was wondering how I would go about achieving that using SQL. I have a field in this table called 'submitted' which holds a standard unix timestamp for when the transaction was recorded.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(submitted,%a)) FROM purchases;
```

My end goal is to create a table with % of all transactions on given days, Monday - Sunday.

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `purchases` (<br />
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,<br />
  `orderinfo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,<br />
  `amount` varchar(5) NOT NULL,<br />
  `reference` varchar(15) NOT NULL,<br />
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,<br />
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `town` varchar(50) NOT NULL,<br />
  `postcode` varchar(12) NOT NULL,<br />
  `submitted` int(11) NOT NULL,<br />
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)<br />
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: You should start by doing a search and looking through the mysql date functions

Comment: Have you tried writing any SQL to achieve this yet?

Comment: Yes, and I cannot get it to work. I will post my workings shortly. Thanks

Comment: This is why you should really be using proper data types for fields. You'd be better updating the timestamp fields to `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the time stamp into date and then take the COUNT, This will fetch count as well as percentage

```
SELECT date ( from_unixtime(submitted) ), count(*) as `count`, count(*)/(select count(*) from purchases)*100 as percentage
FROM purchases
GROUP BY date ( from_unixtime(submitted) );
```

Comment: Hi, I have added my table structure, this great and thanks for prompt response but brings back all records as distinct.

Comment: We also need to exclude the ( 'hours', 'mins' , ..) then GROUP BY wil show count. I am going to give the complete query. DATE() will extract date part of the date :-)

Comment: Thanks so much, I have been literally trying all day!!

Comment: Check the final one now as I am not able to test myself

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want with two nested queries like this (splitted in more lines and indented for better readability)

```
SELECT
    DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submitted`)),
    100 * COUNT(*) /
        (SELECT COUNT(*) from `purchases`)
FROM
    `purchases`
GROUP BY
    DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(`submitted`))
```

Note that the inner query `(SELECT COUNT(*) from purchases)` is used to retrieve the total number of purchases since you want a percentage number.

mysql's `DAYOFWEEK()` returns not the name of the day but an index number from 1 to 7.
You can look here for reference for mysql date ant time functions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

If you just need a query then you're done.

If you want to build a **view** with that query you can't because mysql doesn't allow nested `SELECT` in a view's definition.
You would then split the job in two views, one that just calculates the total number of records, and the second that calculates the percentage.

---

A final note about performance:

if you have a huge amount of records to process this is not performing very fast.

If you then plan to run the query very often this is not good.

In that case since `submitted` is most likely to be written just one time and never changed you may then consider to add another field on your table called `submitted_dayofweek`, type `int`.

When you update `subitted`, update also `submitted_dayofweek` storing `DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(submitted))`.

Finally make sure `submitted_dayofweek` is indexed.

The query becomes

```
SELECT
    `submitted_dayofweek`,
    100 * COUNT(*) /
        (SELECT COUNT(*) from `purchases`)
FROM
    `purchases`
GROUP BY
    `submitted_dayofweek`
```

and will run very fast at the price of a little more storage space used.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope my answer let you understand how the query works.